# Delete a line from a block

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk, sed

I want to search a string and delete it from a block . I tried using `sed` and `awk` but I am not able to figure it out.

Let the blocks be like this:

```
[MAIN]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[3]
three=[4]
three=[5]

[sub]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[3]
three=[4]
three=[5]
```

My need is to go inside the Main block and delete `three=[4]` , by searching the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl version:

```
% perl -pe'BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } if (/\A\[MAIN\]/) { s/^three=\[4\]\n//m }' file
```

will output:

```
[MAIN]
one=[1]
two=[2]
two=[3]
three=[5]

[sub]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[3]
three=[4]
three=[5]
```

BTW, if this is an INI format, you might also want to use a more proper INI parser for that. For example, here's how you would do it using [Config::IOD](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IOD):

```
use Config::IOD;
my $iod = Config::IOD->new; 
my $doc = $iod->read_file("file"); 
$doc->delete_key({
    all  => 1, 
    cond => sub{ 
        my ($self, %args) = @_; 
        return 1 if $args{raw_value} =~ /4/;
    }, 
    "MAIN","three"
);
print $doc->as_string;
```

The code above will delete all "three" key lines under the "MAIN" section if the value of the key contains "4" in it. You can adjust the code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` with `null` record separator:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/\[MAIN\]/{sub(/three=\[ab12\][[:space:]]*/, "")} 1' file
[MAIN]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[4]
three=[5]

[sub]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[3]
three=[4]
three=[5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. This seems to work only if three=[4] but nof if there are more numbers like three=[1234]..

Comment: Sorry to add once again... Can you please make it generic, like lets say the value need not be number alone , It can be string also like
three=[1234] or three[abcdc] etc...also the above removes the space between my blocks , which should not happen.Thanks

Comment: Buddy, this removes all the values in same name, as i mentioned in my question i am looking to delete only one value and the remaining should stay same including spaces.
[MAIN]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[BHAVA]
three=[1234]
three=[5]

[sub]
one=[1]
two=[2]
three=[3]
three=[ANU]
three=[5123]

Comment: awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/\[MAIN\]/{sub(/three=\[[^\]]*\][[:space:]]*/, "")} 1' file>>>>
this one seems great for alphabets,,,,can you please make it generic which can delete numeric, alphabet and alphanumeric values like 
three=[123]
three=[acb]
three=[ab12], based on my value it should delte it , like if i give ab12 , it should delte that line alone

Comment: I suggest you start learning regex. `/three=\[[^\]]*\][[:space:]]*/` will match anything between `three[` and `]`. So all of them `three=[123] three=[acb] three=[ab12]` will be matched and removed.

Comment: I understand the concept buddy , but the thing is the deletion should be based on my input like three=[acb] or three=[ab12] so when i give the input , only the corresponding value should be deleted

Comment: Buddy , thank you i just modified the value and got it as expected

Comment: OK then my very first regex was just doing that, i.e. matching a specific string only. If it worked out for you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[MAIN\]/,/^$/!b;/three=\[4\]/d' file
```

If it is not within the `[MAIN]` block treat as normal. Otherwise delete the matching line(s).